# How to adress this error: Error in renv_snapshot_validate_report(valid, prompt, force) : aborting snapshot due to pre-flight validation failure

Tags: r, shiny, renv

I am deploying a shiny app that locally runs perfectly. Unfortunately I am encountering this error when deploying using shinyapps.io. How can I fix it?

```
ℹ Capturing R dependencies with renv
Error in renv_snapshot_validate_report(valid, prompt, force) : 
  aborting snapshot due to pre-flight validation failure
Calls: <Anonymous> ... snapshotRenvDependencies -> <Anonymous> -> renv_snapshot_validate_report
```

Answer (score 3):

I had multiple issues submitting to shinyapps.io this week, including the error you report but also SSL/TLS connection timeout. I tracked it down to a problem of `renv` to set up the package environment for my app during deploy. When trying to run renv::init() in my project directory, I could reproduce the error.

The problem is that my App was organized as a R-package but was not available via CRAN or GitHub. Hence, upon deploy the package source was unknown to `renv`.

I solved the issue by:

- running `renv::init()` which failed with respect to my local package
- setting up a GitHub repo for my package
- installing my package from a GitHub repo with `renv::install("username/reponame")`

This did yield a valid renv library which in turn resolved the error upon upload.

There should be an easier solution by omitting renv. But I didn't find a solution on  StackOverflow yet.

Comment: I am getting this error, while I am not even using renv :\

Comment: Are you sure to get an error of renv (in renv_snapshot_validate_report) without using renv? Only explanation I can see is that you are using another package which is using renv. Have you used traceback to evaluate the situation?

Comment: Yes I was getting this error ("renv_snapshot_validate") even when I am not using renv in this project. I am using renv in another project. After digging further I found, it was due to "BH" package failing to install as a dependency of another package. I had to download .tar file for BH and install from local to solve the issue.